# Why am I having a logical error with my homework?

Tags: c, fencepost

I'm a junior student in IT. I am facing a problem with the output of the program.
The idea of the program is that I should use functions to read an array of 10 elements, then get the average of the elements, then get the the max and min. I've got the max and min right but the average is showing weird stuff.  Please check the code and tell me what should I do or help me in some way or another.

The out put is (notice that is requesting for 11 numbers instead of 10 and if I change the loop parameters to let it take only 10 then it's showing weird stuff

```
enter the group of integers numbers
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
9
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0the avg is 3.500000
9
1Press any key to continue . . .

// func-sortarray.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#define size  10

void readarray(int []);
void average(int []);
void printArray(int []);
void max(int []);
void min(int []);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int sarray[size];
    readarray(sarray);
    printArray(sarray);
    average(sarray);
    max(sarray);
    min(sarray);
    return 0;
}

void readarray(int a[])
{
    printf("enter the group of integers numbers\n");
    for (int i=0; i<=size-1 ;i++)
        scanf("%d\n",&a[i]);
}

void average(int a[])
{
    int i;
    double avg;
    double total = 0;
    for (i=0; i <= size-1; i++)
    {
        total = total + a[i];
    }

    avg = total /size-1;
    printf("the avg is %f\n",avg);
}

void printArray(int a[])
{
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j <= size - 1; j++) 
        printf( "%2d", a[ j ]);
}

void max(int a[])
{
    int ma =a[0];

    for (int j=0;j<size-1;j++)
    {
        if (ma<a[j])
            ma=a[j];
    }
    printf("%d",ma);
}

void min(int a[])
{
    int mi =a[0];

    for (int j=0;j<size-1;j++)
    {
        if (mi>a[j])
            mi=a[j];
    }
    printf("\n%d",mi);
}
```

thanx in advance

Comment: As a note, instead of doing <= size - 1 everywhere, just do < size

Comment: Also, don't be afraid of reusing variables like i in different functions -- a variable declared inside a function is only "in effect" for that function. This saves you having to think of a bunch of different variable names :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is skipping the first input number because of the '\n' in the scanf() string. To fix it, remove the '\n' from the scanf string, like this:

```
scanf("%d", &a[i]);
```

Comment: thanx a lot
this is the first time idid this
but i learn a lot

Answer (score 3):

You've got some problems with *counting starting with zero* and *multiply before addition* rules. Well, let's get on the first. Most commonly, when you start counting from zero, you do it like this:

```
for(i=0; i < count; i++)
    /* ... */;
```

If you start counting from 1, you do it like this:

```
for(i=1; i <= count; i++)
    /* ... */
```

If you mix those, you get the same result, but it can confuse yourself, and others reading the code:

```
for(i=0; i <= count-1; i++) /* same, but better don't do this */
    /* ... */;
```

In the code calculating the average, you had two bugs. First, you should use parentheses, because of math:

```
avg = total / (size-1); /* there is still one bug */
```

And second, you *have* `size` elements. So you have to divide by `size`, and not by `size-1`:

```
avg = total / size; /* right ! */
```

Comment: I used your code still its taking 11 numbers instead of 10 and when i did the following in the read function for (int i=1; i<size ;i++)

its taking 10 elements but its showing this results
-858993460 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9the avg is -85899341.500000
8
-858993460Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: kristian, yeah sorry. you shouldn't use the "start from 1 loop" i just showed you when you want to start from 0. it's indeed only useful when you want to start with 1 and you want to go N times through the loop body :) but when you want to fill an array you should start at 0 :)

Answer (score 2):

This line is probably the problem:

```
avg = total /size-1;
```

You probably want to instead:

```
avg = total / size;
```

Also, your `max()` and `min()` functions have a loop like this:

```
for (int j=0;j<size-1;j++)
```

This is probably checking one fewer number than you intend.

The above kinds of errors are commonly called "fencepost errors". The name relates to the following question: If you want to build a fence 100 m long, and you want a fencepost every 1 m, how many fenceposts do you need? The answer is not 100 but 101. Another name for this type of error is an "off by one error".

Comment: its still taken 11 numbers how i can make it take only 10 number i tried to change the read function but then i got -8003030303 somthin
please help try it if u can